# Html select onchange get custom attribute value set to other input value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

`onchange` I want to get the select option custom attribute and set to the other input's value. Somehow I cannot get the `course_price` in the input onchange of the select. It only shows the first option value in the input only.

```js
function selectFunction(e) {
  var value1 = $("#test").data('typeid'); //to get value
  document.getElementById("money").value = value1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" onchange="selectFunction(event)">
  <option id="test" data-typeid="<?php echo $row1['course_price']?>" 
  value="<?php echo $row1['course_id']?>"><?php echo $row1['course_name']?>
  </option>
</select>

<input type="number" value="" id="money" class="form-control">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because the `data-typeid` attribute is on the selected `option`, not the `select`, so your jQuery code is looking at the wrong element. You can fix this by using `find()` and `:selected` to get the chosen `option` before reading the `data` attribute from it.

Also note that `on*` attributes are very outdated. You should be using unobtrusive event handlers, something like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('select.form-control').change(function() {
    var typeId = $(this).find('option:selected').data('typeid');
    $("#money").val(typeId);
  }).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control">
  <option data-typeid="1111" value="courseId1">courseName1</option>
  <option data-typeid="2222" value="courseId2">courseName2</option>
</select>

<input type="number" value="" id="money" class="form-control">
```

Answer (score 1):

In your question you are using `#test` which is `id` for all options and so it will always consider first occurance of id `test`. So do not use same id multiple times on the same DOM, change it to `class="test"` if you need it, otherwise, you need to target the selected option, and it will not need any id or class. Check here:

```
var type_id = $('select option:selected').attr('data-typeid');
```

and assign the variable to input box:

```
document.getElementById("money").value =type_id;
```

So the entire updated function will be like this:

```
function selectFunction(e) {
    var type_id = $('select option:selected').attr('data-typeid'); //to get value
    document.getElementById("money").value =type_id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to make it:

```js
$(document).on('change', 'select.form-control', function() {
  var r = $('select.form-control option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]').attr("data-typeid")
  $("#money").val(r)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control">
  <option selected disabled>-- Select one --</option>
  <option data-typeid="1111" value="courseId1">courseName1</option>
  <option data-typeid="2222" value="courseId2">courseName2</option>
</select>

<input type="number" value="" id="money" class="form-control">
```